# Java/Apex methods without bodies but not abstract?

Tags: java, salesforce, apex

I'm trying to understand how someone else's code works. It's in Apex, which is actually an extension of Java 6, so I figure the answer might be with people that know either. The code I'm confused by is as follows (pared down):

```
global class /*System.*/SObject
{
    global Id Id;

    global void addError(Exception msg, Boolean escape)
    {
    }

    global void addError(Exception msg)
    {
    }

    global void clear()
    {
    }
    ....
    global SObject clone(Boolean preserveId)
    {
    }
    ....
    global Object get(SObjectField field)
    {
    }
```

and so on. Too long to include all the methods, but wanted to give a sample.

So these don't say abstract, so they wouldn't appear to be abstract methods, but how do they work if they have no body, no instructions of what is supposed to happen?

There is also a `global class CustomPermission extends SObject`, but none of the methods are called there. So how would one use methods like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the developer was trying to override the built-in sObject methods. It's not a subclass of System, so it probably won't work. Are they ever called by method in another class/trigger?

Is the developer still working there? It could have been an attempt to break existing functionality on the way out the door.